# Can't pass property through navigation route

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass property through navigation route (Drawer Navigation)  according to the basic schema like:

to push params

```
   onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
              user: 'USER_A'
            });
```

to get parameters on Screen2

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const userName = navigation.getParam('user', null);
```

But the problem that Screen2 also contains it's own navigation (Stack Navigation)...

```
const CollapsScr = createStackNavigator({
    Collaps: { screen: Screen2 }
});
```

So when I removing Stack Navigation from Screen2 I can pass parameters without any problems, but I would like to keep this navigation and still be able to pass parameter through Drawer Navigation route. There is any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam()` to obtain the parent parameter you need.

You can also do the other way around.

Before navigating you can do `this.props.navigation. getChildNavigation(°YourGrandChildKey°).setParams()`. Where `YourGrandChildKey` is the one you defined on your Drawer

EDIT.

The first solution i gived, gives you to get the parameter for your specific problem. I don't know how you app will have to work.

On what you asked in the comment, it depends. I've always used redux to store data that i was 100% sure i would've needed all around my app, or data that can change overtime that changes 2 or more screens layouts.

The problem of the first solution is that the data your are taking is stored into another spot of the application, leaving the param `user` visible in the whole drawer.

I would suggest to create a redux base structure. Doing that, you know what data needs to be put on redux that is almost certain needed somewhere else or, at least, is reachable for future updates.

For your specific case, i would move put the user data on redux, as it's helpful giving you information about this session of the app.

As said, you have to choose what solution you think would work better on your app, if you need that variable only for that specific screen, use the second solution, so only that screens has that information, without filling parts of app with unnecessary data.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks a lot, I've tested first suggestion and it works just fine. Could you please elaborate more about you suggestion if it something general and commonly used, either it's something better normally to avoid and use some different ways to pass parameters in such situation like mine... let say pass parameters by using redux or unstate?

Comment: I've tried to use your second solution, but for some reasons it doesn't work either I'm doing something wrong. I'm using just like you said the same route as for navigate. this.props.navigation.getChildNavigation('Screen2').setParams({user: 'USER_A'}). However I can't get it on Screen2 like: this.props.navigation.getParam('user', null) . Am I missing something?

Comment: If you console log the getChildNavigation, does it return something?

Comment: I think I know what going on, but have no idea how to fix it. When I looked into log I found that after first onPress I don't see any parameters passed inside getChildNavigation(Screen2) and this is because the operation is asynchronous, however Screen2 will be rendered after first onPress action. When I'm repeating onPress operation again, I can see that parameters now passed inside getChildNavigation(Screen2) however Screen2 rerendering not happens, so I still see nothing in terms of passed parameters on Screen2. So the  question how to trigger screen rerendering.

Comment: You can use componentDidUpdate inside Screen2 and confront prevProps with this.props in that instance. If they change you can trigger a setState with the new data